# Class Method Not Being Called - Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently learning Python and I'm having a problem where the class method is not being called out. I'm not even sure why to be honest.

I did made some research beforehand and I couldn't really find ones that have a similar situation like mine.

```
class StartUpScreen(tk.Toplevel):
    #instance attributes
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
    def destroyWindow(self):
        self.destroy() 

class bgFrame(tk.Tk):
    def __init__ (self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

app = bgFrame()
authSys = StartUpScreen
app.after(250,authSys)
authSys().destroyWindow()
app.mainloop()
```

I expected the code to execute and destroy the authSys Window after it launches but in the end, it opens up fine but doesn't destroy itself afterwards. Why is that?

Comment: `StartUpScreen` isn't the same thing as `StartUpScreen()`.

Comment: This is because the `auohsys().destroyWindow()` calls before the `after()` as in after it waits 250ms

Comment: Change to `self.after(250, self.destroy)` and place it at the end of `def __init__(self):`